# Why the implicit conversion doesn't work in g++

Tags: c++, gcc

The code bellow can compile in Visual Studio, but is failed in gcc.

```
template<typename Isth>
class A
{
public:
    A(const boost::shared_ptr<Isth>& obj) {...} 
...
};
```

In class B's method:

```
A<Isth1> B::method1
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Isth2> myPtr = boost::make_shared<Isth2>();
  //Isth2 is derived from Isth1;
    ...
    return myPtr;
}
```

In gcc, I got an error "could not convert 'myPtr' from 'boost::shared_ptr' to 'A'"
I think A's constructor should be called when B::method1 return.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to re-post the code.

Comment: Is there any way to make it compile in gcc buy just modifying class A?

Answer (score 5):

The problem was highlighted by others - `shared_ptr<Isth2>` can only be converted to the constructor parameter of `A<Isth1>` if it wouldn't require a user defined conversion. But since it does, that constructor cannot be used.

Again uniform initialization helps to make this work

```
A<Isth1> B::method1()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Isth2> myPtr = boost::make_shared<Isth2>();
  //Isth2 is derived from Isth1;
    ...
    return { myPtr };
}
```

For uniform initialization of a return value, user defined conversions for the constructor parameter is allowed. If you want to only change class `A`, you probably want to write some SFINAE

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_base_of<Isth, T>::value, bool>::type = true>
A(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& obj) {...}
```

You are basically stating *"I am implicitly converting from any shared ptr that points at an object derived from `Isth`"*.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised Visual Studio compiles it. How do you expect to return a shared_ptr instead of an actual object? There is no way `shared_ptr<X>` can be converted to X.

OK, some clarifications are in order. That sort of conversion would have require to custom-conversion - one from `shared_ptr<Isth2>` to `shared_ptr<Isth>`, and another from `shared_ptr<Isth>` to A. Standard explicitly says that only one custom conversion is allowed. GCC is correct.

As to why Visual Studio is converting it, I am not sure. It either eagerly performs double conversion or it does not treat shared_ptr conversions as a custom conversion. Both options are wrong in my view.

Comment: `A` has an implicit conversion constructor that takes a `shared_ptr` as input; it's not too surprising that VS compiles it.

Comment: I think  A(const boost::shared_ptr<Isth>& obj)  works in Visual Studio.

Comment: In addition, there also could be a problem with non-static data member of class A. According to [article in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) if at least one A's member does not have copy constructor with parameter declared as const or const volatile, the copy constructor for A would also have signature without const modifier, i.e. A(A&). As a result, temporary variable of class A created from myPtr cannot be used in a call for A(A&) copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do here multiple implicit conversions:
`boost::shared_ptr<Isth2>` -> `boost::shared_ptr<Isth1>` -> `A<Isth1>`

As C++ standard says in the chapter 12.3 Conversions:

> 4. At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
>      function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

This fixes the compilation:

```
A<Isth1> B::method1()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Isth2> myPtr = boost::make_shared<Isth2>();
  //Isth2 is derived from Isth1;
    ...
    return A<Isth1>(myPtr);
}
```

Updated:

If you dont want to modify the return value, you could modify the constructor in your `A` class:

```
template <class Isth>
class A
{
    ...
    template <class T> A(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) { ... }
    ...
};
```

Comment: return A<Isth1>(myPtr); works in gcc. But I don't want to change my code like this, because I have to modify many methods in many classes. I'm expecting to just modify class A instead.

Comment: It's simple: instead of performing multiple implicit conversions, we're doing a single implicit conversion `boost::shared_ptr<Isth1>` -> `A<Isth2>`. It is now allowed via a new constructor. A missing implicit conversion from `boost::shared_ptr<Isth2>` to `boost::shared_ptr<Isth1> ` is performed inside `A`'s constructor.

Comment: I seems understand this now. Thanks a lot!